# Can't select features in saved WFS-data

Tags: qgis, shapefile, symbology, visibility

I saved some features from a WFS (http://geodienste.bfn.de/wfs/schutzgebiete - the theme "Landschaftsschutzgebiete"). We did this in the past without any problems.

Now, despite the features having attributes, I can't select a feature in the saved/downloaded data, nor use the identify-tool on them. Furthermore, when zooming in, the features disappear - unevenly. Some are visible only up to 1:1000000, others up to 1:500000, etc.

Has anyone encountered this behaviour, and how did you solve it?

Comment: is this with the WFS data or the shapefile?

Comment: With the shapefile.

Comment: I downloaded the data again, this time first saving it as geopackage, then converting it to shapefile. Now the data is selectable and stays visible. Still, the logic why this error appeared would interest me.

Comment: Is the WFS GML response valid?